# Justification of fromJust in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm trying to learn Haskll, and so I was trying out question 26 of Project Euler in Haskell:
http://projecteuler.net/problem=26

My solution to the problem is this:

```
answer26 = answer26' 1000
answer26' n = snd $ maximum $ map (\x -> cycleLength x [1]) [2..n - 1]
    where
    cycleLength n (r:rs)
        | i /= Nothing      = (1 + fromJust i, n)
        | r < n             = cycleLength n $ (10*r):r:rs
        | otherwise         = cycleLength n $ (r `mod` n):r:rs
        where i = elemIndex r rs
```

I realize that this isn't the most efficient algorithm, but seeing as it's naively O(n^3) (where n = 1000) that is not such an issue. What I am concerned about though, is that from my understanding of monads, one of their main properties is that they in some sense "mark" anything that has used the monad. The function "fromJust" seems to fly directly in the face of that. Why does it exist? Also, assuming its existence is justified, is my usage of it in the above code good practice?

Comment: what is "i" in first line of "cycleLength"?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add in the last line there. I've added it now, but thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usage of partial functions (functions that may not return a value) is generally discouraged. Functions like `head` and `fromJust` exist because they're occasionally convenient; you can sometimes write shorter code, which is more understandable to learners. Lots of functional algorithms are expressed in terms of `head` and `tail` and `fromJust` is conceptually the same as `head`.

It's usually preferable to use pattern matching, and to avoid partial functions, because it allows the compiler to catch errors for you. In your code snippet you have carefully checked that the value is never `Nothing`, but in large real-life codebases, code can be many years old, 1000's of lines long and maintained by many developers. It's very easy for a developer to re-order some code and miss out a check like that. With pattern-matching, it's right there in the code structure, not just in some arbitrary Bool expression.

It's not too difficult to replace your usage of `fromJust` with pattern-matching:

```
answer26 = answer26' 1000
answer26' n = snd $ maximum $ map (\x -> cycleLength x [1]) [2..n - 1]
    where
    cycleLength n (r:rs) = case elemIndex r rs of
            Just i  -> (1 + i, n)
            Nothing -> if r < n
                        then cycleLength n $ (10*r):r:rs
                        else cycleLength n $ (r `mod` n):r:rs
```

And (I think) the result is a bit clearer too.

**Edit:** There's an apparently "theoretically ok" place to use `fromJust` mentioned in [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#MonadFix), though you will need someone other than me to explain wtf that is all about.. ;)

Comment: Could you explain why the pattern-matching is safer?

Comment: @Daishisan It's safer because the compiler can warn you if you miss a case. By default it's not enabled actually, but you can turn it on by adding using `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or `-Wall` to enable a long list of warnings (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) And, as I already mentioned, there is the benefit of having the possible branches made explicit in the structure of the code, which is clearer and less likely to be accidentally lost when changing code later.

Answer (score 10):

The monad interface doesn't include any specific function for "extracting" values from a monad, only for putting them in (`return`).

However, it doesn't forbid these kinds of functions either. When they exist, they will be specific to each monad (hence the multitude of run* functions: `runIdentity`, `runReader`, `runWriter`, `runState`... each with different arguments.)

By design, `IO` doesn't have any such "get out" function, and so it serves to "trap" impure values inside the monad. But "not being able to get out" is not a requirement for monads in general. What counts is that they respect the monad laws.

With [comonads](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad/latest/doc/html/Control-Comonad.html#v%3aextract), the situation is reversed. There is a common function to extract values from them (`extract`) that every comonad must implement. But the functions to "put the values in", when they exist, vary for each particular comonad ([env](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Env.html#v%3aenv), [store](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Store.html#v%3astore)...)

As for `fromJust`, it is good practice to avoid it whenever possible because it is a partial function which may fail to match at runtime.

Comment: There are places you may use `fromJust` though. I used just now it in a toy example because I'm backed up by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. When you really, really *know* it is absolutely impossible for a Nothing value to arise in that context it's okay.

Comment: @kqr Often it's a good idea to still avoid `fromJust` in those cases and explicitly handle `Nothing` with something like `error "The fundamental theorem of arithmetic says this can't happen"`. That way it's clear to any reader why ignoring `Nothing` is safe, and if the code is ever refactored in a way that introduces a bug allowing `Nothing` to appear the resulting error gives you a lot more help. Depends on the situation whether it's really worth the hassle though; we've all used `fromJust`.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is so common, there is even a function for that: maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b

In your case, if you do \x -> (cycleLength x [1], x), that is, construct the pair outside cycleLength:

```
    cycleLength n (r:rs) = maybe (cycleLength n rs') (1+) $ elemIndex r rs where
      rs'
        | r < n = (10*r):r:rs
        | otherwise = (r `mod` n):r:rs
```

Also, because you are looking just for a maximum, not the actual value, it will work even with id instead of (1+).